# Pandas inplace fillna changes mean

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, imputation

I have a dataframe with missing values in some columns. I want to fill these missing values with the mean of non-missing entries in the same column. It's easy to show that the average value shouldn't change after the mean imputation. For example, say there's a column `m` missing entries and the sum of `n` non-missing entries is `s`. The mean imputation step will replace the missing entries with the average `s/n`. The mean after this replacement should be

```
mean_after = ((s/n)*m + s)/(m+n) = s/n = mean_before_replacement
```

I think this is a reasonable expectation. However, pandas seems to violate this invariant. Here's an example :

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.__version__
'1.1.0'
>>> df = pd.read_csv("dftest.csv")
>>> df.describe()
                 a
count  1057.000000
mean      1.228950
std       0.420356
min       1.000000
25%       1.000000
50%       1.000000
75%       1.000000
max       2.000000
>>> df.notna().sum()
a    1057
dtype: int64
>>> df.isna().sum()
a    260
dtype: int64
>>> mean_before = df.a.mean()
>>> mean_before
1.2289498580889309
>>> df.fillna(dict(df.mean()), inplace=True)
>>> mean_after = df.a.mean()
>>> mean_after
1.228949858088931
>>> mean_before == mean_after
False
```

Am I missing something here ?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: curious what your scientific domain where precision down to 10^-15 is needed

Comment: @PaulH Thanks. The main issue I'm facing is that the data frame is serialized after the imputation step. This data is later fed into a regression model after a scaling step (zero 1 and std of 1). I don't know enough about the numerical stability of optimization algorithms to claim that this truncation causes an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're seeing [machine epsilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon). We were generally taught that floating point arithmetic was only accurate to about 15 digits after the decimal.

If I'm not mistaken you can multiply all values by the same multiple (eg 1000), do the arithmetic, then divide by that same multiple in order to retain precision. Another solution would be to round to the 14th digit to allow for that assertion to be true.

For a mathematical explanation, see this [math SO post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2780436/machine-epsilon-meaning).